# How to jsdoc constructor function returning a new object properly?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

For example I have a code like this:

```
export { createPerson }
const createPerson = (name, age) => {
  const getFullData = () => {
    return `Person ${name} is ${age} years old`
  }
  return {
    get name() {
      return "Person name is " + name
    },
    age,
    getFullData,
  }
}
```

I tried to document it like this:

```
/**
 * @module people
 */
export { createPerson }
/**
 * Generates a new Person
 * @param {string} name Person name
 * @param {number} age Person age
 * @returns {Person}
 */
const createPerson = (name, age) => {
  /**
   * Gets full data for this person
   */
  const getFullData = () => {
    return `Person ${name} is ${age} years old`
  }
  /**
   * A Person
   * @constructs Person
   */
  const person = {
    /**
     * Name string
     * @type {string}
     */
    get name() {
      return 'Person name is' + name
    },
    /**
     * @prop {number}
     */
    age,
    /**
     * @method
     */
    getFullData,
  }

  return person
}
```

With code like this I get a proper documentation of the constructor function createPerson with the returning type link to Person, where I see all of it's props and methods.

But I don't see getFullData and age documentation. All @borrows variants I tryed didn't work. @inheritdocs don't work either. How can I get it without copying documentation? Because in a real code there are too many methods returned from the constructor and doc-copying will make a mess and it's too ugly by it's essence to duplicate docs.

Comment: This seems like it would be solved if it was just a `class` instead of a `Function`. Though if you want to do this, you could use a `@typedef {Object} Person` to define the structure and say your method `@returns {Person}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do what I want! It's @borrows. I just didn't read documentation carefully before — that part concerning naming and pathing in JSDoc system.
And here is a working solution:

```
/**
 * @module people
 */
export { createPerson }

/**
 * Generates a new Person
 * @param {string} name Person name
 * @param {number} age Person age
 * @returns {Person}
 */
const createPerson = (name, age) => {
  /**
   * Gets full data for this person
   * @returns {string}
   */
  const getFullData = () => {
    return `Person ${name} is ${age} years old`
  }
  /**
   * @constructs Person
   * @borrows module:people~createPerson~getFullData as getFullData
   */
  const person = {
    /**
     * Name text
     * @type {string}
     */
    get name() {
      return 'Person name is' + name
    },
    /**
     * @prop {number}
     */
    age,
    getFullData,
  }

  return person
}
```

Now `getFullData` method's documentation is inherited, but I still need to document the `age` prop. Age wasn't initialized in the `createPerson` code, so I cannot borrow it from there.